# Do we have logging feature for SQL AUDIT like we have it for transaction and error logs in SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Do we have logging feature for SQL AUDIT like we have it for transaction and error logs in SQL server 2008 ????

Answer (score 0):

There's two forms to audit a SQL Server

The SQL Profile:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650699.aspx

And DDL Trigger's

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx